# How to refresh a WPF subtree without knowing what is in the subtree (Especially all bindings that only depend on converter rather than source value)?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Background:

I use converters to acquire values for most of my binding statement because the bindings are so complicated that even multi-binding cannot satisfy. I have to calculate the value in the converters and return the value. Also I use OneWay or OneTime binding just to show the correct value. When user changes a value, I use Handlers to set the value. The Handlers are also complex program which cannot be simply replaced by TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding. Actually in this case the DataContext does not have any meaning. I use converters. Another reason of using converters is that all Controls are loaded dynamically using many DataTemplates and it's hard to create dynamic DataContext for each Controls in each DataTemplate.

With above background, my application works fine. I'm looking for solutions for our new problem below.

I have many group of Buttons each represent a warehouse containing different type of items.
When double-click a Button, a detail window pops up and user can modify the items. Those items can be represented by CheckBox, Combobox, TextBlocks, TextBox, etc.

For user's convenience, I duplicated some of the frequently-modified Controls from the popup window onto the Button itself (WPF allows Button to contain sub-controls), so that user can directly modify the items without double-click and popup the detail window.

Each Button could contain unknown number of sub-controls such as CheckBox, Combobox, TextBlocks, etc. Here "unknown" means that in the future developer can duplicate any controls onto the Button if the Controls for those items are deemed frequently-modified.

Everything works fine so far.

When user modifies an item in the popup window and closes the window, I used to reload the DataTemplate for the whole window so that everything is refreshed and the controls duplicated onto the Button can synch up with the value modified from inside the popup window.

Everything still works fine so far.

The problem happens when the application runs on machine with slow hardware, where performance is an issue. On a much slower machine, reloading the whole DataTemplate for the whole application that contains many Buttons is quite slow.

So I'm looking for ways to just refresh the Button that is double-clicked, not all Buttons. However, I searched a couple of days and could not find ideal solution of refreshing a WPF sub-tree.

I tried to travel the sub-tree of the Button to assign null to the DataContext property and then assign back the old DataContext, but the binding seems not triggered and the converters were not called.

I saw someone suggested to use something like below:

```
((ComboBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty)
                  .UpdateTarget();
```

That demands that I know the Control and its property that has bindings. I think I can do the same for all possible Controls and properties but it does not seem a future-proof solution.

Anybody knows an effective way of refreshing a WPF sub-tree without knowing what is in the sub-tree?

Comment: Without reading thru all of this, I'm going to say: `create a proper ViewModel and all your problems will magically disappear`.

Comment: @HighCore, I'm loving your work here... you always put a smile on my face.

Comment: Appreciate your comment, but I don't see what kind of ViewModel can resolve it. I need dynamically choose to load from XAML at runtime several Grid DataTemplates each containing an arbitrary number of Buttons with binding statement. How do I create a ViewModel so that I can trigger refreshing individual Button and its sub-tree without refreshing the others? The Grid DataTemplate must be predefined and hard-coded to reflect certain artistic layout and shape and sequence of Buttons.

Comment: @user1943928 All I can hear as you talk is `ItemsControl... ItemsControl... ItemsControl...` - post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.